# Why assign target = Object.assign(target, source);

Tags: javascript

I'm following a guide on state management, in which there is a line
`self.state = Object.assign(self.state, newState);`
which confuses me. Object.assign mutates its target and returns that target, so why would you assign it to the same target again? I don't see how this is different from `Object.assign(self.state, newState);`
Am I missing something?

Comment: You're right, that code does not make sense. Guide should be fixed.

Comment: I'd guess it's some library use `self.state` as gettter/setter or proxy, and do not provide other method to do/indicate a direct update.

Comment: If this is react, `Object.assign(self.state, newState)` is also incorrect as it mutates the state

Comment: Object.assign() is vanilia

Comment: It might try to make the `self.state` mutation obvious.